# Visual Studio 2019 - Function Syntax Highlight in Gold (Olive)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Starting with Visual Studio 2019, the syntax highlighter now colors functions in a goldish color (actually called Olive I guess). Since yesterday, somehow this no longer works.

I went to `Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Color`, changed the `Identifier` to Olive but it actually switched most of the code to Olive.

[image: Example Screenshot from VS]

For example, previously, `AddGlobalServices`, `AddMvc`, `SetCompatibilityVersion` and `AddMemoryCache` where Olive colored.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, go to `Options -> Text Editor -> Basic -> Advanced -> Editor Color Scheme` and set it to Visual Studio 2019

This way, the highlighting of functions and methods will change to Gold.